# List<Base> contains different Derived types. How to convert safely with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I recently ran into a situation where I received a `List<Base>` when I was expecting a `List<Derived>`, which is really what I needed.  It turns out that the Derived is a subclass of Base and `List<Base>` actually contained the Derived objects I needed.

However, the List I'm getting is returned from a third party API and I'm concerned now that it may eventually come back with more than one type that derives from Base.  I need to convert `List<Base>` to `List<Derived>` and I want to make sure that I'm only converting the type that I need while safely skipping any other subtypes that aren't related to the one I need.

For instance, if I have the following class hierarchy:

```
public class Derived : Base {}
public class DerivedOne : Base {}
public class Base {public int i;}
```

Then I have the following results from the below code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Base> bList = new List<Base>() {new Derived(), new DerivedOne()};
    List<Derived> dList = new List<Derived>();
    /*InvalidCastException*/
    // dList = bList.ConvertAll(x => (Derived)x);

    /*InvalidCastException*/
    // dList = new List<Derived>(bList.Cast<Derived>());

    /*Works, but essentially 'converts' DerivedOne object
     to Derived object, which would be unwanted.*/
    dList = bList.ConvertAll(x => new Derived{i = x.i});
    // or
    dList = bList.Select(x => new Derived{i = x.i}).ToList();

    /* Works, but is there a cleaner way using LINQ? */
    dList = new List<Derived>();
    foreach(Base b in bList) {
        Derived d = b as Derived;
        if (d != null)
            dList.Add(d);
    }
}
```

So, my question is this: How can I create a `List<Derived>` from the `List<Base>` using LINQ without throwing an InvalidCastException or creating Derived objects from the unrelated DerivedOne class?

Comment: do you know `OfType` method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could you use

```
dList.Where(i=> i is Derived).ToList().ConvertAll(i => (Derived)i);
```

or

```
dList.OfType<Derived>().ToList()
```

Comment: The first approach has to iterate the elements twice, which makes it slower (and harder to read).

Answer (score 0):

Ga ber-ber,

Lei Yang stated it the best answer. The best solution in terms of maintainability and re-usability with the framework is LINQ's OfType method. It exists as an extension of an IEnumerable and is part of the System.Linq namespace.

Here is a resource link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

### EDIT

Here is the code you have above:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Base> bList = new List<Base>() {new Derived(), new DerivedOne()};
    List<Derived> dList = bList.OfType<Derived>().ToList();
}
```

Comment: Ok.  Can you provide an example?

Comment: Ga ber-ber see example above.

Answer (score 0):

To extract only the `Derived` items from a sequence of `Base`items use Enumerable.OfType.

Sequences of different types:
    IEnumerable someBaseTypes = ...
    IEnumerable someDerivedTypes = ...
    IEnumerable someOtherDerivedTypes = ...

Mix them. You don't anymore which type they are:

```
IEnumerable<Base> mixedCollection = someBaseTypes
    .Concat(someDerivedTypes.Cast<Base>())
    .Concat(someOtherDerivedTypes.Cast<Base>());
```

To get only the Derived ones. Use `OfType`

IEnumerable onlyDerivedTypes = mixedCollection
       .OfType();

Be aware though, if the collection also contains sub classes of Derived, you'll also have them in your result